# Where to write ViewModel class in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have one doubt that where to write ViewModel class in MVC4. I could see that there is two folder called Models and ViewModel. In case of writing parentmodel  and viewmodel class, under which folder i have to write it.

Comment: You can put the class wherever you like, but try and keep the location, naming etc consistent.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a **ViewModels** folder and keep all view-models in it by creating hierarchy same as your `Views` folder in it.

Like suppose you have `Index.cshtml` and `About.cshtml` in

> View -> Home

folder, then put the `view-models` defined for `Index` and `About` in

> ViewModels -> Home -> IndexViewModel.cs

and

> ViewModels -> Home -> AboutViewModel.cs

This helps to keep code separation in development.
I hope you got an idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately its up to preference.  Im quite new to MVC but i like to keep my models and ViewModels in one place (if its not a huge project!) that way the file paths are similar and easier to keep a track of. If it's a view model i just like to put ViewModel at the end of the name. For e.g:

**UserViewModel.cs / UserVM.cs (your view models)**

**User.cs(just a regular model)**

If it's a big project where you have lots of both, it's quite acceptable to put them all in a different project all together, again keeping your file paths accessible.